# Adding line breaks in plain text when using Razor

Tags: razormediator

I'm working on a Razor template to add plain text to an outbound email. I notice that if I just add the fields without any logic:

```
@Fields.Title  
@Fields.Subtitle
```

I am able to get line breaks. However if I use logic to check if the fields exist there are no line breaks in the plain text. For example:

```
@if (Fields.Title != null) { @Fields.Title}  
@if (Fields.Subtitle != null) { @Fields.Subtitle }
```

Outputs:

TitleSubtitle

I have tried to use \n and \r\n both inside and out of quotes. How do I add these line breaks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the @ signifies that you are breaking out of text mode you need to use a text tag to add the line breaks in for plain text.

```
   @if(Fields.Title != null) {  
   <text>@Fields.Title</text>  
   }  
   @if(Fields.Subtitle != null) {  
   <text>@Fields.Subtitle</text>  
   }
```

Outputs:

Title
Subtitle